# Find number of multiples of n numbers in a given range

Tags: java, algorithm

I am facing a problem where I have been given a range:
consider: `start, end`

And N numbers:  `n1,n2,n3....nn`

I am supposed to find quantity of multiples of  all N numbers in range(start,end)

What I have tried -

**I have tried creating a HashSet and then finding one by one multiples of N numbers in range start,end (Insert each multiple in hashset). Then at the end size of the set is the answer.**

This works. But doesn't work with large input.

Consider-

```
Input: 1 10 3 6 3 7
Output: 4
```

Explanation-

```
Range: 1 to 10
N: 3
Numbers: 6, 3, 7
Multiples of 3 = 3,6,9 (quantity =3)
Multiples of 6 =6 (quantity =1, but 6 is common)
Multiples of 7 = 7 (quantity=1)
Total quantity = 4
```

Hence output is 4. Output is 4 not 5, because 6 is a multiple of both 3,6. (avoid duplication).

Comment: "I have tried creating a HashSet and then..." **show, don't tell**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple answer would be this one:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    /* Initialization */
    int min = 1;
    int max = 1000;
    final Set<Integer> solutions = new HashSet<>();
    final Set<Integer> items = new HashSet<>();
    Collections.addAll(items, 3,6,7);


    /* Solution */
    items.forEach(element -> solutions.addAll(findMultiples(element, min, max)));

    System.out.println("Total quantity: " + solutions.size());
    solutions.forEach(System.out::println);
}

private static Collection<Integer> findMultiples(int element, int min, int max) {
    if (min % element != 0) {
        min = element * (min / element + 1);
    }
    final Collection<Integer> solutions = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = min; i < max; i+=element) {
        solutions.add(i);
    }

    return solutions;
}
```

For each element, you look for the first Integer which is a multiple of it and is in the given range. Then, you iterate with a step of `element`. Using your `HashSet`, it becomes easy to find the result.

Comment: int min = 32964;
    int max = 73489;
    final Set<Integer> solutions = new HashSet<>();
    final Set<Integer> items = new HashSet<>();
    Collections.addAll(items, 587, 438, 510, 939, 833, 674, 770, 795);

Doesn't work with this.

Comment: @NaMo > What is the issue? Do you know the result? If so, I would be happy to check my result.

Comment: result is supposed to be 484, instead of 494.

Comment: @NaMo > Are you sure? When I run my tests, I can't find any issue. Here they are: `System.out.println(solutions.stream().filter(solution -> items.stream().noneMatch(question -> solution % question == 0)).collect(Collectors.toList()));` and `System.out.println(solutions.stream().filter(solution -> solution > max || solution < min).collect(Collectors.toList()));`. The first one looks for solutions that are not multiple of items. The second one looks for solutions that are not included in the range.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the problem, you have a list of numbers and a range. 
You want to know how many numbers in the range is a multiple of one of the numbers in the list.

To approach this problem, you want to define divisibility `isDivisible` and multiplicity `isMultiple`. 
Notice that I defined `isMultiple` as whether `number` is multiple of one of the numbers in the list `units` instead of just another number.

Finally, you want to check which numbers in your range matches the criteria.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Solver {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Solver solver = new Solver();
        final List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(3, 6, 3, 7);
        final int result = solver.numberOfMultiples(1, 10, input);
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    }

    public int numberOfMultiples(final int start, final int end, final List<Integer> numbers) {
        final List<Integer> multiples = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (isMultiple(i, numbers)) {
                multiples.add(i);
            }
        }
        return multiples.size();
    }

    private boolean isMultiple(final int number, final List<Integer> units) {
        for (final int unit : units) {
            if (isDivisible(number, unit)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isDivisible(final int number, final int unit) {
        return number % unit == 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another solution with some test data.  No HashSets are really necessary to accomplish this task.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class MultipleCount {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<List<Integer>> testData = List.of(List.of(1, 10, 3, 6, 3, 7),
            List.of(32964, 73489, 587, 438, 510, 939, 833, 674, 770, 795),
            List.of(1, 10, 2, 2, 2, 2));

      for (List<Integer> list : testData) {
         System.out.println(list);
         int m = getMultiples(list);
         System.out.println(m);
      }
   }

   public static int getMultiples(List<Integer> data) {
      List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();

      for (int k : data.subList(2, data.size())) {
         for (int i = data.get(0); i <= data.get(1); i++) {
            int r = i;
            while (r % k == 0) {
               if (!results.contains(r)) {
                  results.add(r);
               }
               r = r / k;
            }
         }
      }
      return results.size();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Then at the end substract size of set with size of range(end-start+1).** Why ??

The **HashSet** you made is the actual quantity which you want to get. In above question your `HashSet` Contains `3,6,9,7`. then why are you subtracting this set size from Initial set size. Simple get the `set.size()` . This is your Quantity.

Comment: Sorry I actually told you the solution about the rest of the question. I have edited it out. Yes set.size() is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the number of multiples very quickly using the following function:

```
public static int multiples(int lower, int upper, int divider) {
    int number = ((int) (upper / divider)) - ((int) (lower / divider));
    return number;
}
```